# Excel Popup Blocking Other Spreadsheet Interaction

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two coworkers that utilize an Excel file that has VB forms built into it.

User A has two open excel files on different screens. When they activate the user form for modification, it prevents interaction with either of the excel files while the form is active.

User B also has two open excel files but even with the form open, they are able to manipulate the excel file on the other screen that is not attached to the form.

Why do User A and User B have these differences?

Thanks

Comment: Do they have 2 excel files open or 2 excel instances? they're very different things.

Comment: What version(s) of Excel are they running?